# Polynomial irreducible - maximal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, proof-verification, ideals, irreducible-polynomials

I have a couple of ideals which I wonder if I correctly classify as maximal/prime ideal.

$I_1 = \langle 2x^2 + 9x -3\rangle$, $I_2 = \langle x - 1\rangle$

$\mathbf 1)$ Is $I_1$ a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?

Yes, since $I_1$ is irreducible with $p=3$ using Eisenstein's criterion, thus maximal ideal.

$\mathbf 2)$ Is $I_2$ a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?

Yes, since $I_2$ is obviously irreducible, and thus a maximal ideal, and every maximal ideal is a prime ideal.

$\mathbf 3)$ Is $I_2$ a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

<s>Yes, $I_2$ is obviously irreducible, and thus a maximal ideal.</s>

$\mathbf{Edit:}$ No, as it is not a field.
$$
$$

Am I right in my conclusions?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Parts 1 and 2 are ok. But irreducibility of a generating polynomial implies maximality only when the ring of coefficients is a field, so 3 is wrong. Can you think of a bigger proper ideal? For examples you might add another generator that is a constant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a theorem that you can use: Given a commutative ring $R$ with identity, $I$ is a maximal ideal in $R$ if and only if $R/I$ is a field. (Similarly, $I$ is a prime ideal if and only if $R/I$ is an integral domain.)

What do elements in $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x - 1\rangle$ look like? Do they form a field?

Comment: Obviously $\mathbb{Z}$ does not have multiplicative inverse for all elements and is thus not a field. So the extension is not a field. My bad there! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 17):

In a commutative ring $R$ with $1$ and $a\ne 0$
\begin{array}\
R/(a) \text{ integral domain} &\iff &(a) \text{ prime ideal} & \iff & a \text{ prime}\\
&&&  & & \\
\Uparrow&&(a) \text{ maximal among principal} & \Longleftarrow & a \text{ irreducible} &\\
 && &  &  & \\
R/(a) \text{ is a field} & \iff &(a) \text{ maximal ideal} 
\end{array}

In an integral domain $R$ and $a\ne 0$
\begin{array}\
R/(a) \text{ integral domain} &\iff &(a) \text{ prime ideal} & \iff & a \text{ prime}\\
&&&  & \Downarrow & \\
\Uparrow&&(a) \text{ maximal among principal} & \iff & a \text{ irreducible} &\\
 && &  &  & \\
R/(a) \text{ is a field} & \iff &(a) \text{ maximal ideal} 
\end{array}

In a UFD $R$ and $a\ne 0$

\begin{array}\
R/(a) \text{ integral domain} &\iff &(a) \text{ prime ideal} & \iff & a \text{ prime}\\
&&&  & \Updownarrow & \\
\Uparrow &&(a) \text{ maximal among principal} & \iff & a \text{ irreducible} &\\
 && &  &  & \\
R/(a) \text{ is a field} & \iff &(a) \text{ maximal ideal} 
\end{array}

In a PID $R$ and $a\ne 0$
\begin{array}\
R/(a) \text{ integral domain} &\iff &(a) \text{ prime ideal} & \iff & a \text{ prime}\\
&& &  & \Updownarrow & \\
\Uparrow &&(a) \text{ maximal among principal} & \iff & a \text{ irreducible} &\\
 &&\Downarrow &  &  & \\
R/(a) \text{ is a field} & \iff &(a) \text{ maximal ideal} 
\end{array}

Comment: I have an exercise  saying : in a PID give an example of $(p)$ maximal and $p$ not irreducible, but from your answer this can't be true, right??

Comment: The implication $a$ prime $\implies$ $a$ irreducible in the first chart is wrong. Example: The element $2 \in \mathbb Z / 6 \mathbb Z$ is prime but not irreducible because $2 = 4\cdot  2$.

Comment: The implication $(a)$ prime ideal $\implies$ $a$ prime in each chart is wrong in the case $a=0$.

Answer (score 5):

In 3, your argument is wrong. In an integral domain, $a$ is irreducible iff $(a)$ is maximal among **principal ideals**, but $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is not a PID, thus you cannot conclude that $(a)$ is maximal. In fact it is not, because $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x-1\rangle$ is not a field. So for example $\langle 2,x-1\rangle$ is a maximal ideal containing $\langle x-1\rangle$.